# Unable to load csv, strange chars in file python

Tags: python, database, numpy, csv

I tried to load my csv into python and got this output.

code

```
df=pd.read_csv(f"{getcwd()}\\Au\\AU 1.csv",delimiter=',',encoding='cp1252')
print(df)
```

file encoding result be 'cp1252'

I got this output:

```
 ÿþW  Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2

0      NaN         NaN         NaN

1      NaN         NaN         NaN

2      NaN         NaN         NaN

....

55150  NaN         NaN         NaN
```

AU 1.csv

```
Wavelength (nm),Absorbance (AU),Std.Dev.

਍㄀㤀　Ⰰ　⸀㈀㤀㈀㜀㌀㠀㤀㄀㐀㐀㠀㤀㜀㐀㘀Ⰰ　⸀　㠀㈀㌀㌀㈀㤀㘀㐀㐀㠀㔀㜀㜀㌀㐀ഀഀ

191,0.0829615592956543,0.0572289788579017

਍㄀㤀㈀Ⰰ　⸀㈀　㈀㤀㠀㠀㄀㐀㜀㜀㌀㔀㔀㤀㘀Ⰰ　⸀　㜀㤀㈀　㠀㐀㤀　㄀㌀㈀㐀㄀㤀㘀ഀഀ

193,0.0574579238891602,0.05101896546718

਍㄀㤀㐀Ⰰ　⸀㄀㄀㠀　㐀㤀㘀㈀㄀㔀㠀㈀　㌀㄀Ⰰ　⸀　㔀㄀㐀㈀㈀㜀㘀㈀　㠀㠀㔀㐀㠀㈀ഀഀ

195,0.174723625183105,0.0458854494589069

਍㄀㤀㘀Ⰰ　⸀㄀㜀㠀　㄀㜀㄀㌀㤀㐀㌀㐀㠀㄀㐀Ⰰ　⸀　㐀㄀㜀　㌀㜀㘀㌀㤀㜀㜀㘀㈀㄀㄀ഀഀ
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your problem, you are facing issues due to different language in your CSV (the strange characters are Japanese alphabets).You might wanna check out for different language support for pandas.

I will update this post if I find something useful on this.

New Update:

[image]you should consider codec cp932 (For more details: [check this out](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings))

I have attached my code below:

```
  import pandas as pd
```

import os

df = pd.read_csv(f"{os.getcwd()}\AU 1.csv", delimiter=',', encoding='cp932')
print(df)

[image]

Although it still contains some unrecognized characters..

Comment: I noticed one thing the numbers in Wavelenght shound be 190-191-192... so the 'japanese' should be the missing lines.

Comment: I assume the data came with the csv file. In that case your program is running well.. its just the data in the file is not what you are expecting. Just need to tune it in to proper codec.